# subversion outage, seeking for a workaround

Tags: svn, version-control

My subversion server is crashed, repairing it will take a pair of weeks. Unfortunately, I've found myself version-control-addicted and can't write code without being assisted by versioning.

I'm seeking for a workaround system. Something should overtake my current code, track the changes and in future replay the changes and the log messages to the repaired subversion server. So the net result will be as there were no outage at all.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: I do use git. For other projects.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, it is a great chance to move to mercurial/git!

Answer (score 0):

The point with subversion is that the history is kept centralized in the server, so if it is down and if you have no dumps (which you should have had daily produced by e.g. a `crontab` running `svnadmin dump` for backup purposes on the server) you are stuck.

The advantage of using GIT (for your next project maybe) is that the history is duplicated, and even if the server crashes you have it kept locally.

Comment: I was downvoted. Why? Am I wrong in thinking that `svn` don't keep history information locally??

Answer (score 0):

You could use `git` as a temporal frontend for SVN. `git-svn` is a pretty good frontend for SVN servers which allows delayed pushing to the server. I'm not sure if it will work with a simple working copy (without downloading the history from a live SVN server), but it might be worth a try.

Additionally, get into the habits of making **backups**. A server outage should take minutes to hours to fix by rededicating other hardware with data from the backup. Not weeks.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary version system, I used RCS. After the subversion server was up again, I just collected RCS files, used "rlog" to get revisions and commit messages, them manually for each revision: "co" from RCS and "svn commit" to subversion. It took a bit of time, but the result was perfect.